# Create a dynamic heatmap in R

Tags: r, graph, grid, heatmap

I want to create a piece of code that allows me to create a heatmap based of values within a df.
However, the values do not always appear (i.e. some sets of data contain 4 classes, some 3 and some 2).

For example one df could look like this:

```
column <- c(rep(c(1),5),rep(c(2),5),rep(c(3),5),rep(c(4),5),rep(c(5),5))
row <- rep(1:5, 5)
class <- c(0,0,1,2,1,2,2,3,0,1,2,3,1,2,0,1,0,0,2,3,3,2,2,2,1)
df <- data.frame(column, row, class)
df
```

Whereas another would have the same number of rows but only have classes 0, 1 and 3 (for example).

I want to colour the respective grids with the following logic:

```
class 0 = red
class 1 = green
class 2 = blue
class 3 = grey
```

I want to be able to pass through different sets of data though the heatmap code and not have to change anything to get the desired result.

NB: the number of rows of data will always be the same and the size of the heatmap will always be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `ggplot` you can create a named vector with the values of your class and the colors you want and then use `scale_fill_manual`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(123)
column <- c(rep(c(1),5),rep(c(2),5),rep(c(3),5),rep(c(4),5),rep(c(5),5))
row <- rep(1:5, 5)
class <- c(0,0,1,2,1,2,2,3,0,1,2,3,1,2,0,1,0,0,2,3,3,2,2,2,1)
df <- data.frame(column, row, class)


cols <- c('0' = 'red', '1' = 'green', '2' = 'blue', '3' = 'grey')
ggplot(df, aes(column, row, fill= factor(class))) + 
  geom_tile()+
  scale_fill_manual(values = cols)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I can't believe how simple that was. I already had the heatmap created, but I was massively over complicating the dynamic aspect. Thanks again.